# "The file is not displayed in the editor because it is either binary or uses an unsupported text encoding"

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-code

I want to open a `HTML` file on `VSCode` but in the editor, there is a sentence like this:

[image]

I don't know how to fix it.

I tried to open it anyway but the file looks like this:

[image]

Comment: It's definitely binary and not html. How did you generate the file's contents?

Comment: Can you open the same file in Notepad? 

Can you create a new html file in vs code and write code in it?